# How to flatten a type (not an enumerable) through Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

All of the examples for SelectMany I see are flattening arrays of arrays and so on. I have a different angle on this question.

I have an array of a type, and I want to extract that type's contents into a stream. Here's my example code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    class Foo
    {
        public int X, Y;
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> Flatten(Foo foo)
    {
        yield return foo.X;
        yield return foo.Y;
    }

    public static void RunSnippet()
    {
        var foos = new List<Foo>()
            {
                new Foo() { X = 1, Y = 2 },
                new Foo() { X = 2, Y = 4 },
                new Foo() { X = 3, Y = 6 },
            };

        var query = foos.SelectMany(x => Flatten(x));
        foreach (var x in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs what I'd like: 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6.

Can I eliminate the yields? I know that the plumbing to support that is nontrivial, and probably has a significant cost. Is it possible to do it all in linq?

I feel like I'm very close to the answer and am just missing the magic keyword to search on. :)

UPDATE:

As mentioned in the answer below, it works to use something like this:

```
foos.SelectMany(x => new[] { x.X, x.Y });
```

However, I was hoping to find a way to do this without generating n/2 temporary arrays. I'm running this against a large selection set.

Comment: What's wrong with the yield solution?

Comment: I read an article that talked about how yield worked underneath and it's not cheap. I'd also like to have something inline, next to where the work is being done, instead of requiring a totally separate function. Lambdas ftw.

Comment: Where does "it's not cheap" come from? Do you have a link to the article?

Comment: Here's one article I had read that led me to this conclusion

http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to avoid temporary array creation and yet you want short and nice code using LINQ, you can go with -

```
var query = foos.Aggregate(
    new List<int>(), 
    (acc, x) => { acc.Add(x.X); acc.Add(x.Y); return acc; }
    );
```

Comment: Yes! This is the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about the cost of the compiler trickery involved with `yield` and/or the cost of `SelectMany`, you could try to minimize the impact of those by not calling `Flatten` on each `Foo` but instead `Flatten` the `foos` directly:

```
public class MyClass
{
    class Foo
    {
        public int X, Y;
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> Flatten(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            yield return foo.X;
            yield return foo.Y;
        }
    }

    public static void RunSnippet()
    {
        var foos = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo() { X = 1, Y = 2 },
            new Foo() { X = 2, Y = 4 },
            new Foo() { X = 3, Y = 6 },
        };

        var query = Flatten(foos);

        foreach (var x in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

I've run a small test app for this and I have seen that there are some performance benefits with the second implementation. On my machine, flattening 100,000 `Foo`s with both algorithms took 36ms and 13ms, respectively. As always YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var query = foos.SelectMany(x => new[] { x.X, x.Y });
```

Comment: Oops - I forgot to mention that I don't want to do it this way. Trying to avoid the temporary array creation. Will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of reverses `IEnumerable<T>`, and is more comparable to what we did with PushLINQ - but it is a lot **simpler** than implementing an iterator block on the fly (through IL), while retaining blinding performance thanks to dynamic-method; the use of `object` is in case your data is non-orthogonal and you need multiple types through the same API:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

// the type we want to iterate efficiently without hard code
class Foo
{
    public int X, Y;
}
// what we want to do with each item of data
class DemoPusher : IPusher<int>
{
    public void Push(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
// interface for the above implementation
interface IPusher<T>
{
    void Push(T value);
}
static class Program
{
    // see it working
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { X = 1, Y = 2 };
        var target = new DemoPusher();
        var pushMethod = CreatePusher<int>(typeof(Foo));
        pushMethod(foo, target);       
    }
    // here be dragons
    static Action<object, IPusher<T>> CreatePusher<T>(Type source)
    {
        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("pusher",
            typeof(void), new[] { typeof(object), typeof(IPusher<T>) }, source);
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        var loc = il.DeclareLocal(source);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, source);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, loc);
        MethodInfo push = typeof(IPusher<T>).GetMethod("Push");
        foreach (var field in source.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance
            | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        {
            if (field.FieldType != typeof(T)) continue;
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, loc);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
            il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, push, null);
        }
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (Action<object, IPusher<T>>)
            method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object, IPusher<T>>));
    }

}
```